# OpenVPN connects, but I can't see the network

Tags: routing, openvpn, bridge, openbsd

I'm trying to setup openvpn in bridge mode.  I've done this before on a openbsd router.  Now I have an internal machine that is running openbsd.  the client is a windows 7 laptop.

The setups is as follows.

My local lan at home is 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0 with a gateway of 10.0.10.1
The vpn server is 10.0.10.15

I am forwarding port 9999 udp public to 10.0.10.15.

on the server:
/etc/hostname.tun0

```
link0 up
```

/etc/bridgename.bridge0

```
add pcn0
add tun0
up
```

/etc/openvpn.conf

```
dev-type tap
dev tun0
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
user nobody
group nobody
daemon openvpn
chroot /var/empty
port 9999
proto udp
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
management 127.0.0.1 9998 /etc/openvpn/mgmt.pwd
server-bridge 10.0.10.1 255.255.255.0 10.0.10.240 10.0.10.244
push "route 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/keys/ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
max-clients 5
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 4
mute 20
```

on the client:
openvpn.conf:

```
client
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 9999 #my ip is really here
proto udp
dev tap
dev-node VPN
nobind
comp-lzo
link-mtu 1590
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
management 127.0.0.1 9090 "mgmt.pwd"
ns-cert-type server
ca "ca.crt"
cert "tim-work-laptop.crt"
key "tim-work-laptop.key"
tls-client
tls-auth "ta.key" 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
pull
verb 2
```

when I run an ifconfig -a on the server:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 33204
        priority: 0
        groups: lo
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3
pcn0: flags=8b43<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        lladdr 08:00:27:04:df:8c
        priority: 0
        groups: egress
        media: Ethernet none
        status: active
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe04:df8c%pcn0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 10.0.10.15 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.10.255
enc0: flags=0<> mtu 1536
        priority: 0
tun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        priority: 0
        groups: tun
bridge0: flags=0<> mtu 1500
        priority: 0
        groups: bridge
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> mtu 33204
        priority: 0
        groups: pflog
```

my firewall config is open since it is an internal box:

```
int_if="pcn0"
vpn_if="tun0"
br_if="bridge0"
vpn="9999"
ntp="123"
dns="53"

#set require-order no
set skip on lo
scrub in

pass in proto udp from any to any port $ntp
pass in proto {tcp,udp} from any to any port $dns
pass in         # to establish keep-state

#vpn/bridge info
pass in quick on $int_if proto udp from any to $int_if port $vpn
pass in quick on {$vpn_if,$br_if} proto {tcp,udp,icmp} from any to any
pass out quick on {$vpn_if,$br_if} proto {tcp,udp,icmp} from any to any
```

The windows client connects, gives me an ip of 10.0.10.240 as expected, and the openvpn gui icon is green.  However, I am unable to ping anything on my local lan at home, include 10.0.10.15.

Any ideas?

I'm using the following guides:
http://blog.innerewut.de/2005/07/04/openvpn-2-0-on-openbsd
http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html
http://www.kernel-panic.it/openbsd/vpn/vpn4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really silly thing...

there needs to be a carriage return at the end of the hostname.tun0 and bridgename.bridge0 files.

Comment: Tim,

Can you describe the "carriage return" ?

Comment: it's needs a newline character at the end, like \n or \r.  In other words, go the end of the line and press [enter]

Comment: "Carriage return" (`CR`) and "line feed" (`LF`) are ASCII characters for marking end of the line.